# Possible to check a value is a compile time constant in Rust?

Tags: macros, rust

There are cases when inline functions or macros will expand into a lot of code. However, when used with constants, dead branches can be optimized away.

I could add a comment in the code:

```
// foo arg is always a constant, dead branches will be removed
```

But I'd rather add some kind of static assertion to ensure this is always the case.

Is there a way in Rust to check if a value is a compile time constant?

Something like GCC's `__builtin_constant_p`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the type of the value or expression is fixed and known in advance, you can define a local constant and initialize it with the value or expression. If you don't otherwise use the constant, prefix its name with an underscore to suppress compiler warnings about the constant being unused. This only works with macros, though.

```
const _ASSERT_COMPILE_TIME_CONSTANT: i32 = $arg;
```

---

The nightly compiler also supports defining "const functions", i.e. functions that can be used in contexts where the compiler requires an expression that can be evaluated at compile time. The body of those functions are subject to restrictions, but call sites of const functions that don't need to be evaluated at compile time can pass expressions that cannot be evaluated at compile time as arguments, so defining a const function doesn't provide the guarantee you're asking for.

---

If the type of the value or expression cannot be specified in the macro, then we can't omit it, as `const` requires that the type be specified. However, we can use a generic const function that returns a fixed type in a `const` initializer!

```
// at the beginning of the crate
#![feature(const_fn)]

// in the macro's body
const fn _swallow<T>(_x: T) { () }
const _ASSERT_COMPILE_TIME_CONSTANT: () = _swallow($arg);
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Francis answer, this is a macro that can be used to ensure constant value.

```
macro_rules! ensure_const_expr {
    ($value:expr, $t:ty) => {
        {
            const _IGNORE: $t = $value;
        }
    }
}


// in a functions body
ensure_const_expr!(some_variable, i32);
```

---

Note the extra braces are needed so multiple uses don't fail with:

```
error: a value named `_IGNORE` has already been defined in this block
```