# Is it possible in Rust to determine whether a function argument is a compile-time constant?

Tags: rust, compile-time

In Rust, it's possible to assert that the result of an expression is a compile-time constant [by using it to initialise a `const`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39178209/11875845). However, this sort of check doesn't work across a function boundary. For example, the following code errors at compile time:

```
struct StringLiteral(&'static str);
impl StringLiteral {
    const fn new(s: &'static str) -> Self {
        const _: &'static str = s;
        StringLiteral(s)
    }
}
```

with "attempt to use a non-constant value in a constant", even if `StringLiteral::new` is never called.

It seems like it should be possible to make this sort of assertion by checking to see whether the `new` function is actually running at compile-time or not – `const fn`s can be called either at runtime or compile-time, and somehow asserting that the function is being run at compile-time would be one possible solution to the problem. But I haven't been able to find a function/method/intrinsic in the standard library that would determine that.

Is it possible to write a `const fn` such that it runs successfully only when its argument is a compile-time constant (either via detecting whether it's being run at compile-time, or via some other mechanism)?

One approach that does *not* work: simply requiring a `'static` lifetime is insufficient because it's possible to create values with such lifetimes during runtime, e.g. via the use of `String::into_boxed_str` followed by `Box::leak`.

(Context: I'm attempting to produce a data type that can contain only literal strings, not strings that were calculated at runtime, as a sort of defence-in-depth mechanism that statically guarantees that the strings can't be controlled by an attacker: the requirement that a string must have been literally present in the program's source code makes it impossible for an attacker to put their own custom strings there.)

Comment: The only mechanism like this I'm aware of is [std::fmt::Arguments](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Arguments.html) and it's associated macros, but that is a special-case within the compiler itself.

Comment: The function would have to behave differently in const vs non const contexts and if that's allowed is an [open issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/77745).

Comment: Function arguments are never considered compile-time constants. If you want to parametrize a function with a compile-time constant, your best option is to use a trait with an associated constant. You can implement the trait on multiple dummy types for the different constants you want to use, and then pass the dummy type as a parameter.

Comment: @cafce25 I think that bug is a different issue. This question is about treating function arguments as compile time constants, which would give us a weird new kind of const generics. I'm not aware of any serious proposal to do this (and it's never going to fly anyway).

Comment: @SvenMarnach: that suggestion does actually solve the issue I'm having (via a different route from the ones I was exploring above). It might be worth writing as an answer, so that it can be accepted, as it seems likely to be the best available option for other people who are having the same issue that I am.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Sven's comment, you can create a trait with an associated constant.

```rs
pub trait CompileTime {
    const C: &'static str;
}

pub struct HelloStr;

impl CompileTime for HelloStr {
    const C: &'static str = "Hello";
}
```

This is a decent amount of boilerplate for a simple thing, so you may want a macro, such as:

```rs
macro_rules! comptime {
    ($name:ident, $string:literal) => {
        pub struct $name;

        impl CompileTime for $name {
            const C: &'static str = $string;
        }
    }
}

comptime!(HelloStr, "Hello");
```

## Future rust

When [`adt_const_params`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/95174) becomes stable, you can use a const generic `&str`, which works better with your original code:

```rs
const fn new<const S: &'static str>()
```